# get data from multi-dimensional array using PHP code

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get this data `[label] => For Rent` from a multi-dimensional array. Here is my array

```
Array ( [listing_id] => 0 
        [fields] => 
                   Array ( [1] => Property House 7 [2] => 30 [4] => sdfasd
                           [11] => Bungalow [10] => Philippines [12] => 1800100
                           [13] => 1 [14] => 1 [15] => Yes [16] => Yes [17] => Yes
                           [18] => Yes [26] => Yes [25] => Yes [24] => Yes
                           [23] => Yes [22] => Yes [21] => Yes [20] => Yes [19] => Yes) 
        [fees] => Array ( 
            [30] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [label] => For Rent [amount] => 0.00
                                      [days] => 7 [images] => 0
                                      [categories] => 
                                        Array ( [all] => 0 
                                [categories] => Array ( [0] => 30 ) ) [extra_data] => ) ) 

                                [images] => Array ( ) [thumbnail_id] => 0 )
```

How will I echo the `label` that has a value of `For Rent` using PHP code

Comment: your array contains `stdClass Object` . How can it possible.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, You can put whatever you want in an array, including object instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $yourArray['fees'][30]->label
```

It's not just an array... it's an array with an object in it.  Use the `->` to access object properties.

Comment: so what if I want to echo the 30? in here `$yourArray['fees'][30]->label`

Comment: @KevinSteveManingo, The value of `30` is an object!  If you want to echo it, its `__toString()` method will be called.  You probably didn't define one, since it is just a StdObject.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$array[fees][30]->label
```

Where `$array` is whatever you're top level variable is.

Answer (score 0):

You can access any value of array by their keys. simply access  `For Rent` like this :-

```
echo $arrayName['fees'][30]->label
```

This will display For Rent like ( An Arrow operator because to access an object attribute you have to use this )